# Building React App inside of Node server best practice

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins

Have a react repo and a node repo. The are on the same root directory like so:

--myReactApp

--myNodeServer

I have a script in the React app that builds the React app and places the generated files into the Node server's public directory.

```
npm run-script build
#Remove the files from the server directory
rm -r ../myNodeServer/public/*
#copy over new files
cp -r ./build/. ../myNodeServer/public
```

This is all good, but now I am doing CI/CD with Jenkin's pipeline and it pulls the myNodeServer repo that does not have the React app in the public folder. I don't think it is best practice to include generated files in the myNodeServer's public directory, so I don't want to check in the React app into the the Node repo.

What do developer's generally do in the this situation. Is it possible to pull from 2 different repos in a pipeline script.

Right now my script looks like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "Node8"}
  environment {
    DBPASSWORD     = credentials('DBPASSWORD')
    DEPLOYSECRET   = credentials('DEPLOYSECRET')
  }
  stages {
    stage('NPM Install') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm install'
      }
    }
    stage('Unit Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'env PORT=3090 DBUSER=username DBPASSWORD=$DBPASSWORD DEPLOYSecret=$DEPLOYSECRET ENV=unitTest ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --timeout 10000 --timeout 0 --ui bdd --recursive ./test'
      }
    }
  }
}
```